# How to pass a value from one page to another in angular.js

Tags: angularjs

this is my code

```
<md-whiteframe class="whiteframe" layout-align="center space-around" 
    ng-repeat="scdlr in day" ng-click="showDetails(data.name)" flex>
    {{scdlr.name}}<br>
    {{scdlr.creative_id}}<br>
    {{scdlr.status}}
</md-whiteframe>
```

and in controller

```
$scope.showDetails = function(e)
    {

        $mdDialog.show({
            templateUrl        : 'app/main/apps/vendors/scheduler/dialogs/detail.html',
            targetEvent        : e,
            clickOutsideToClose: true
        });


    }
```

when i click the whiteframe a pop-up of page detail.html is coming. all i want is data.name(the parameter passed in ng-click) in detail.html.is it possible, i'm new to angular.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `locals -{object=}:` An object containing key/value pairs. The keys will be used as names of values to inject into the controller. For example, 
`locals: {three: 3}` --would inject three into the controller, with the value.

[Reference](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdDialog)

Comment: if i put a controller argument like controller : 'EventDetailController', it' says  Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'EventDetailController' is not a function, got undefined. how to fix this@Nidhin T T

Answer (score 1):

You could save data.name in rootscope:

```
$scope.showDetails = function(name){
$rootScope.name=name;
//your code
}
```

and in html you could access it through {{$root.name}}.rootScope would be accessible everywhere and it would be treated as global variable.

Answer (score 0):

Use angular Services or Factory and inject the name of respective service or factory into the detail.html controller to use data globally.

Visit Official site: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services

Answer (score 0):

Hi when using  $mdDialog, if you want to send data, then use locals attribute to send data.

```
$scope.showDetails = function(e) {
                         $mdDialog.show({
                             templateUrl        : 'app/main/apps/vendors/scheduler/dialogs/detail.html',
                             targetEvent        : e,
                             clickOutsideToClose: true,
                             locals: {
                                   items: $scope.data // data you want to pass
                             }
                         });
                     }

    }
```

For more info visit: [Angular js $mdDialog documentation](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdDialog)

Comment: if i put a controller argument like controller : 'EventDetailController', it' says Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'EventDetailController' is not a function, got undefined. how to fix this@rroxysam